# ddply() and using length to count within a specific set of rows in R

Tags: r, plyr

Hopefully someone can help me out with this seemingly easy question, that I just can't figure out!

```
name = c('alan', 'alan', 'alan','alan', 'alan', 'alan', 'albert','albert','albert', 'alvin','alvin','alvin','alvin')
var = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 ,0)
df = data.frame(name, var)
```

The data set that I have is below:

```
     name var
1    alan 0
2    alan 1
3    alan 0
4    alan 1
5    alan 1
6    alan 0
7  albert 0
8  albert 0
9  albert 1
10  alvin 1
11  alvin 1
12  alvin 0
13  alvin 0
```

I would like to use ddply in order to count all the 1 but for each name. So in other words, Alan is supposed to get three 1, Albert gets one 1, and Alvin gets two 1s. 
So the ideal output is:

```
           name counter
    1   alan          3
    2 albert          1
    3  alvin          2
```

Here's the code that I have that is not working:

```
df.ddply = ddply(df, c('name'), transform, counter=length(df[df['var']>0, 'var']))
```

The reason why I would like to use the length function here is because the values for the var column can be from 0-9.

This is the output from the above line:

```
    name counter
1   alan          6
2 albert          6
3  alvin          6
```

Am I missing something here? Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many times does this question need to be answered before people can find it with a bit of searching??????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with `plyr`:

```
df.ddply <- ddply(df, "name", summarise, counter=length(var[var == 1]))
```

Comment: I was hoping instead to count the number of times where var > 0 because the var column has values ranging from 0-9. Sorry, I was not explicit enough in my question.

Comment: see edit. Also have a look at the other answers, there are good options available

Comment: Awesome!!! Can you explain the code? Sorry I'm quite new to R, is there a reason why my code does a counter of all the 1s instead of by names given that I told it to group by name?

Comment: have a look at what `df[df['var']>0, 'var']` returns - you're not getting what you expect

Answer (score 6):

There is no need for `plyr` here, it is neither faster or easier to read than base R. Just use `agggregate`

```
aggregate(var ~ name, df, function(x) sum(x == 1))
#     name var
# 1   alan   3
# 2 albert   1
# 3  alvin   2
```

Or try `tapply`

```
tapply(df$var, df$name, function(x) sum(x == 1))
# alan albert  alvin 
#    3      1      2
```

Another possible solution using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  tally(var == 1)
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
#     name n
# 1   alan 3
# 2 albert 1
# 3  alvin 2
```

Though my tool of choice is always the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(counter = sum(var == 1)), name]
#      name counter
# 1:   alan       3
# 2: albert       1
# 3:  alvin       2
```

Or (as @Arun mentions)

```
setDT(df)[var == 1, .(counter = .N), name]
```

Though this should be the fastest for a big data set (keyed `by` combined with binary search)

```
setkey(df, var)[J(1), .(counter = .N), name]
```

Comment: a `count` solution would be: `count(df, name, var) %>% filter(var == 1)`. In a compact way, `filter(count(df, name, var), var == 1)`.

Comment: We can also do: `setDT(df)[var==1, .N, by=name]` for data.table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with `dplyr` (the successor to plyr)

```
library(dplyr)
counts <- df %>%
            group_by(name) %>%
            summarise(
              counter = sum(var))
```

Comment: In this case you're exploiting that var only takes the values 1 or 0 (which gets ignored). You might like to `sum(var==1)`